# How to add text or label into jpanel grid in java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I have a JPanel the creates panel grids that is clickable. I am trying to add a label when the particular grid in a panel is clicked. I have tried to put the code using add method, but no label was added to it.

Code:

```
// ================================================
// creates panel grids that is clickable

public class CenterPanel extends JPanel {
      static JLabel labelText = new JLabel("SCHEDULED",JLabel.CENTER); 

    public CenterPanel(int row, int col) {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                JPanel pan = new JPanel();

                pan.setEnabled(true);
                pan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3, 3));
                pan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                // an exception to not click the top row and most left column headers
                if (i != 0 && j != 0) {
                    pan.addMouseListener(new BoxListener()); // add a mouse listener to make the panels clickable
                }
                // set names for each panel for later use
                pan.setName("PANEL_" + i + "_" + j);
                add(pan);
            }

        }
    }

    //Class that defines what happens when a panel is clicked
    public static class BoxListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
        {   
              JPanel clickedBox =(JPanel)me.getSource(); 
              clickedBox.setBackground(Color.RED); 
    // NEED TO ADD Label into the grid when clicked
    // tried to add clickedBox.add(labelText);  //nothing happened

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Either use buttons, with a different icon (some containing text) for each button state, or continue with panels and use a `CardLayout`to flip between states.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: the way you do it, the jlabel can only be added to 1 panel at a time. also your code is working, but the ui does not update the right way. you can test it by clicking 1 panel and then resizing your window

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working absolutely fine. The problem is that when you are adding component(JLabel) to the JPanel at runtime, you are not revalidating the panel, so changes won't appear till you revalidate your panel. Use `revalidate()` method on your panel in which you are adding the component.
Following is the modified `BoxListener` class

```
static class BoxListener extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
    {   
        JPanel clickedBox =(JPanel)me.getSource(); 
        clickedBox.setBackground(Color.RED);
        clickedBox.add(labelText);
        //add below method
        clickedBox.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to add the clickedBox.revalidate and it works fine. But when I tried to resize the window, it removes the label from the clickedBox panel. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Just changed to anonymous class and then was able to use setVisible(true).  I added a few other things just to get it to work on my end too.

```
public class CenterPanel extends JFrame {
static JLabel labelText = new JLabel("SCHEDULED",JLabel.CENTER);

public CenterPanel(int row, int col) {
    this.setSize(row*50,  col*50);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
    //setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            JPanel pan = new JPanel();



            pan.setEnabled(true);
            pan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(3, 3));
            pan.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            // an exception to not click the top row and most left column headers
            if (i != 0 && j != 0) {
                pan.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                        pan.setBackground(Color.RED);
                        pan.add(new JLabel("HIT"));
                        setVisible(true);
                    }
                }); // add a mouse listener to make the panels clickable
            }
            // set names for each panel for later use
            pan.setName("PANEL_" + i + "_" + j);
            add(pan);
            setVisible(true);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: this still has some curious behavior. at least on my pc. once all except 1 panels are clicked, i click the last and all other become white while last one becomes red